# how to show a "login failed" message in html, depending on servlet response

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, authentication

simple layout (going to be implemented in a complex project)
I've got a simple user-password Login Page.
clicking submit sends a request with those parameters to a LoginServlet.
this servlet checks the database for a match- if it ends positivley the user is being re-directed to the next page.

**However**, if this ends badly- the user is re-directed to the same page, Login.html

I'm looking for a way to "add" some extra-weight to this re-direction, that as the user gets to the login page more than once, a warning appears along the form stating "the login details are wrong" or something...

how can I achieve this?
from the servlet- response.SendRedirect?
or Forward(request,response)?

on the html, how can I achieve this behavior with java script?
I tried exploring the XMLHttpRequest object, but his method dont seem to appear to retrieve anything useful i'm trying to attach to the response headers.

attaching here my servlet code- just to give you some refernce- but I'm open to suggestions, thanks.

```
try {
            AdminFacade af = (AdminFacade) CouponSystem.getInstance().login(name, password, type);

            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            System.out.println("LOGIN SERVLET:session id: " + session.getId());

            session.setAttribute("facade", af);
            System.out.println("LOGIN SERVLET:facade id: " + af);

            session.setAttribute("userType", "admin");
            response.setHeader("test1", "this is a test header");
             response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("login.html"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the servlet, if login credentials are wrong then you do :

```
request.setAttribute("messageResponse","Login failed: wrong login credentials");
```

And this you need to check this value in your page like this :

```
if(request.getAttribute("messageResponse")!=null){
      out.println(request.getAttribute("messageResponse"));
}
```

You need to write above java code in your page.